# ng-tags-input not working correctly with autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm adding tag by selecting from list (which is populated using $http request). The tag is added but the text which I have typed that remains there with ng-invalid-tag class.

ScreenShots
1) Initially,

[image]

2) Typing 3 letters to get HTTP Call.

[image]

3) Now after selection of first Skill "Angular Js'.

[image]

4) It shows that .input.invalid-tag is enabled. And which doesn't clear the placeholder.

My Input Tag is as below.

```
<tags-input ng-model="employerMyCandidatesCtrl.skillList" placeholder="Skills..."
    replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
    add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
    display-property="skillName"
    on-tag-added="employerMyCandidatesCtrl.addTagToSkillData($tag)"
    on-tag-removed="employerMyCandidatesCtrl.removeTagFromSkillData($tag)">
  <auto-complete
    source="employerMyCandidatesCtrl.loadSkillData($query)"
    displayProperty="skillName" debounce-delay="500"
    min-length="3">
  </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Controller Code is as below.

```
vm.skillList = [];
vm.loadSkillData = function(query) {
  return EmployerServices.getAllSkillsPromise(query); // $http call.
};

vm.addTagToSkillData = function(tag) {
  if (_.findIndex(vm.skillList, tag) < 0) {
    vm.skillList.push(tag);
  }
};

vm.removeTagFromSkillData = function(tag) {
  var ind = _.findIndex(vm.skillList, tag) > -1 ? vm.skillList.splice(ind, 1) : '';
};
```

Is any configuration mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 attributes for `onTagAdding, onTagAdded, onTagRemoving, onTagRemoved` so the basic difference between the attributes ending with adding compared to those ending with added is

```
Adding suffixed tags are expecting a boolean which when true will be added
or removed based on the tag used.
```

But onTagAdded/Removed already adds the tag, before the function is called hence we can do some additional logic or else strip the ng-model of the added value or add back the removed value(not very easy).

Check the below JSFiddle to see the four attributes in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/a3qfmcs6/12/)

I have made a custom service to supply the data, so the final answer to your question will be to use the appropriate attribute (`onTagAdding, onTagAdded, onTagRemoving, onTagRemoved`) based on your usecase. From the above code, I think we need not write `onTagAdded, onTagRemoved` since its done automatically.